# Cannot import values from my .flaskenv file

Tags: python, flask

I am working on my first python and flask app from a udemy course. Shortly after finishing the project I and pushing my code to github, (per the instructions of the author) I realized the author had me store my local db password and my production db password in my app.py file, not very safe. But the author also had me create a .flaskenv file. That reminded me of using .dotenv in my javascript and node projects, so I assume I should store my db passwords in that file and then put the file it my gitignore.

However, I haven't found a solution for reading values from that file into my app.py file. I've searched through the Flask docs and haven't found anything helpful.

I did read in a seperate thread that I could  do the following

.flaskenv :

```
SQL_PW=myFakePassword
```

from my app.py:

```
from flask import Flask , render_template , request, redirect, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:'+os.SQL_PW+'@localhost/quotes'
```

However, when I try to implement that solution I get the following error

> AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'SQL_PW'

What is the best way to read values from my .flaskenv file into my app.py file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the dotenv module and a .env file instead of .flaskenv. Install with:

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

Add the following to you app.py:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
```

Then the secrets will be available as environment variables.

You access it with:

```
os.environ.get("SQL_PW")
```